# How can i change php local value on nginx?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

As I know on Apache I can write in .htaccess something like "php_flag asp_tags on" and local value for this folder(site) can be differ from master value.
On NGINX (Ubuntu) it isn't working... Installing second,third, etc PHP is unacceptable.

Comment: With nginx you possibly will use fastcgi, use fastcgi_param PHP_FLAG ... http://serverfault.com/questions/557780/different-php-configs-in-nginx

Comment: Both of this variants isn't working
location / {
   fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "asp_tags=on";
}

location / {
   fastcgi_param PHP_FLAG "asp_tags=on";
}

Comment: please, provide the full nginx config, config snippet your provided doesn't make sense for me

Comment: You asking about this [Link to Gist](https://gist.github.com/Hellek/dd08782caae8da120ff8)?

Comment: IMHO fastcgi_param directive within one location context has no impact to others no-nested locations. Try it where fastcgi_pass is.

Comment: For now i prefered ini_set() in index.php. Not the best choise, but it's working. Tnx for help